# Scrolling is quite laggy in my implementation using jetpack compose paging

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

I tried to implement pagination in my app using compose. Here you can find full code : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Compose

First I am showing a loading indicator, and then loads items from TMDb API. So I have following composable method :

```
@Composable
fun <T : TMDbItem> PagingScreen(
    viewModel: BasePagingViewModel<T>,
    onClick: (TMDbItem) -> Unit,
) {
    val lazyTMDbItems = viewModel.pagingDataFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    when (lazyTMDbItems.loadState.refresh) {
        is LoadState.Loading -> {
            TMDbProgressBar()
        }
        is LoadState.Error -> {
            val message =
                (lazyTMDbItems.loadState.refresh as? LoadState.Error)?.error?.message ?: return

            lazyTMDbItems.apply {
                ErrorScreen(
                    message = message,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    refresh = { retry() }
                )
            }
        }
        else -> {
            LazyTMDbItemGrid(lazyTMDbItems, onClick)
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in the else section it calls LazyTMDbItemGrid composable function :

```
@Composable
private fun <T : TMDbItem> LazyTMDbItemGrid(
    lazyTMDbItems: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    onClick: (TMDbItem) -> Unit
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(COLUMN_COUNT),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = Dimens.GridSpacing,
            end = Dimens.GridSpacing,
            bottom = WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(LocalDensity.current)
                .toDp().dp.plus(
                    Dimens.GridSpacing
                )
        ),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
            Dimens.GridSpacing,
            Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ),
        content = {

            items(lazyTMDbItems.itemCount) { index ->
                val tmdbItem = lazyTMDbItems[index]
                tmdbItem?.let {
                    TMDbItemContent(
                        it,
                        Modifier
                            .height(320.dp)
                            .padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing),
                        onClick
                    )
                }
            }

            lazyTMDbItems.apply {
                when (loadState.append) {
                    is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        item(span = span) {
                            LoadingRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing))
                        }
                    }
                    is LoadState.Error -> {
                        val message =
                            (loadState.append as? LoadState.Error)?.error?.message ?: return@apply

                        item(span = span) {
                            ErrorScreen(
                                message = message,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing),
                                refresh = { retry() })
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        })
}
```

In order to load images in the ImageView asynchronously, I have following function :

```
@Composable
private fun BoxScope.TMDbItemPoster(posterUrl: String?, tmdbItemName: String) {
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = posterUrl,
        error = rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Filled.BrokenImage),
        placeholder = rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Default.Movie)
    )
    val colorFilter = when (painter.state) {
        is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading, is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error -> ColorFilter.tint(
            MaterialTheme.colors.imageTint
        )
        else -> null
    }
    val scale =
        if (painter.state !is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) ContentScale.Fit else ContentScale.FillBounds

    Image(
        painter = painter,
        colorFilter = colorFilter,
        contentDescription = tmdbItemName,
        contentScale = scale,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    )
}
```

The problem is when I am scrolling very fast in the part of screen that images are not loaded yet, it is quite laggy. Based on my research there is no problem with my image loading using coil library, but I do not know why it is laggy. Do you have any suggestion about this?

**Addenda :**

I have reported the issue here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264847068

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refer to this issue address on github to solve it. At present, Coil is combined with Compose's LazyVerticalGrid and LazyColumn, and the sliding sense is lagging:

https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/1337